# Can a <script defer> execute before a <script> without defer or async?

Tags: javascript

Given e.g.

```
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js" defer onload="functionFromFirstJs()"></script>
```

Is it possible that the call the `functionFromFirstJs` ever fails because first.js could be executed after second.js?

Could the behavior differ if the script elements are placed at the end of the body vs the head?

Comment: In some very old IEs it's possible, but in modern browsers `defer` works as intended. It executes after the body has been parsed, the script without defer is parsed "in place".

Comment: @Teemu for old browsers that's didn't have defer, didn't scripts run in order anyway.  So it still wouldn't be possible for first to execute after second, even if the browser loaded in parallel, it would wait until all scripts loaded.

Comment: @Keith `defer` was  available in IE5, and it hadn't always worked correctly in IE. But as you said, if `defer` is not present/supported, the order is kept anyway.

Comment: @Teemu  But what has that to do with what I just said?.  In older browsers how could second execute before first?.

Comment: AFAIK, the browser will not "see" the second script tag until the first one has been downloaded and executed.